# How to use hcl write to set expressions with ${}?

Tags: go, terraform, hcl

I am trying to use hclwrite to generate .tf files.

According to the example in [hclwrite Example](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclwrite#example-package-GenerateFromScratch), I can generate variables like `foo = env.PATH`, but I don't know how to generate more forms of expressions. For example, the following.

```
stage = "prod"
foo   = "hello${var.stage}"
```

when i set foo with

```
SetAttributeValue("foo", cty.StringVal("hello${bar}"))
```

i get

```
foo = "hello$${bar}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hclwrite` tool currently has no facility to automatically generate arbitrary expressions. Its helper functions are limited only to generating plain references and literal values. `SetAttributeValue` is the one for literal values, and so that's why the library correctly escaped the `${` sequence in your string, to ensure that it will be interpreted literally.

If you want to construct a more elaborate expression then you'll need to do so manually by assembling the tokens that form the expression and then calling [`SetAttributeRaw`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclwrite#Body.SetAttributeRaw) instead.

In the case of your example, it looks like you'd need to generate the following eight tokens:

- `TokenOQuote` with the bytes `"`
- `TokenQuotedLit` with the bytes `hello`
- `TokenTemplateInterp` with the bytes `${`
- `TokenIdent` with the bytes `var`
- `TokenDot` with the bytes `.`
- `TokenIdent` with the bytes `stage`
- `TokenTemplateSeqEnd` with the bytes `}`
- `TokenCQuote` with the bytes `"`

The `SetAttributeValue` function is automating the simpler case of generating three tokens: `TokenOQuote`, `TokenQuotedLit`, `TokenCQuote`.

You can potentially automate the creation of tokens for the `var.stage` portion of this expression by using [`TokensForTraversal`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclwrite#TokensForTraversal), which is what `SetAttributeTraversal` does internally. However, unless you already have a parsed `hcl.Traversal` representing `var.stage`, or unless you need things to be more dynamic than you've shown in practice, I expect that it would take more code to construct that input traversal than to just write out the three tokens literally as I showed above.

Comment: If I can't use cty.Value to define all variables, I can only use low-level Token to be compatible with ordinary Value and Traversal. Thank you for your answer.